# "establishment" vs. "facility" vs. "institution"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What are the differences and similarities among those three words? I looked them up in the dictionary and saw that their definitions are barely wide.

*Could someone make it more specific? Thank you.*

Comment: What specifically did you read in dictionaries, and what exactly wasn't clear?

Comment: @alphabet Is it the same if I use "education institution/facility" and they all mean buildings?

Comment: A facility is a building; an institution and an establishment are organisations, though often based in a building. We would say '**educational** institution'.

Comment: While this question is somewhat inelegantly worded, it is not a trivial question; the answer to it won't be obvious from the dictionary entries for these words.